# Cisco Small Business RV 325 - Loose internet when VLAN enabled

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan

I tried many times to make my router work in the configuration I want, but no matter what I do, it won't work..

The configuration :

ISP router: IP address 192.168.99.1 all ports forwarded to 192.168.99.2 
connected to a Cisco Small Business RV 325 configured with the 192.168.99.2 IP address on WAN port.

I set some VLANs on the RV 325 :

- VLAN 1 => default, gateway 192.168.99.254 No DHCP
- VLAN 10 => for workstations IP 192.168.1.1/24 GW 192.168.1.1 DHCP Enabled
- VLAN 20 => for VOIP IP 192.168.2.1/24 GW 192.168.2.1 No DHCP
- VLAN 30 => for IP cameras IP 192.168.3.1/24 GW 192.168.3.1 No DHCP

By default the VLAN option is not enabled. I can access to the internet, but I don't have the benefit of the VLANs.
When I enable it, I can't get access to the internet anymore...

Most of the time, I get an error referring to DNS error so I suspected a missing firewall rule.

So, I've tried multiple firewall rules (even ANY to ANY), but I never succeeded.

What can I do to make this router work with VLANs?

[This](https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/RV325_Emulators/RV325_Emulator_v1-1-0-09/default.htm) is the interface I have to setup for the router

Comment: Are you setting different subnets for each VLAN? If so Each VLAN needs a gateway in its own subnet. For instance, your VLAN 10 in the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet would need a gateway in the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet

Comment: Hi Ron, yes I have set one for each vlan.

Comment: The next question is whether or not you have DHCP set up uniquely for each VLAN.

Comment: For VLAN 10, yes. For the others, no.

Comment: Event for VLAN 1, I loose the internet connection

Comment: What is the ip and mask of the WAN port?

Comment: The IP of the WAN port, router side : 192.168.99.2 - 255.255.255.0
The ISP router is 192.168.99.1 - 255.255.255.0

Comment: I believe the VLANs are only for the internal LAN ports and don't apply to the WAN ports on this device. Your VLAN 1 IP address overlaps with the WAN interface IP address putting the same subnet on both sides of the RV325. This should only work if the WAN port is configured as a "Transparent Bridge" as per documentation. For normal operation these two subnets should be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, thank you for your questions and answers.

The solution was provided by [YLearn](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/33/ylearn) :

> I believe the VLANs are only for the internal LAN ports and don't apply to the WAN ports on this device. Your VLAN 1 IP address overlaps with the WAN interface IP address putting the same subnet on both sides of the RV325. This should only work if the WAN port is configured as a "Transparent Bridge" as per documentation. For normal operation these two subnets should be different.

I changed the VLAN1 to another IP range and enabled VLAN. It worked like a charm.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up, looking for an answer.